# После получение JSON от VK API не могу преобразовать JSON в List<T>

Tags: c#, json, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

При получении `response` от VK API и конвертировании JSON в `List<Audio>` появляется такая ошибка:

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unexpected token while deserializing object: PropertyName. Path '', line 1, position 33.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно преобразовать JSON в `List<Audio>`?

Вот код:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form2().Show();
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    public List<Audio> audioList = null;
    public class Audio
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int owner_id { get; set; }
        public string artist { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public int duration { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string lyrics_id { get; set; }
        public int genre_id { get; set; }
        //id: 232745053,
        //owner_id: 34,
        //artist: 'Ambassadeurs',
        //title: 'Sparks',
        //duration: 274,
        //url: 'http://cs6164.vk....M_lGEJhqRK8d5OQZngI',
        //lyrics_id: 120266970,
        //genre_id: 18
    }
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (!Settings1.Default.auth)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        WebRequest request =
            WebRequest.Create("https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?user_id=" + Settings1.Default.user_ID + "&v=5.50&need_user=0&access_token=" + Settings1.Default.user_token);

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader dataReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = dataReader.ReadToEnd();
        dataReader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        responseFromServer = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(responseFromServer);
        //MessageBox.Show(responseFromServer);
        JToken token = JToken.Parse(responseFromServer);
        audioList = Enumerable.Skip(token["response"].Children(), 1).Select(c => c.ToObject<Audio>()).ToList();
        
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < audioList.Count(); i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(audioList[i].artist + " - " + audioList[i].title);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Json:

```
{
    response: {
        count: 505,
        items: [
            {
                id: '34',
                photo: 'http://cs7009.vk....3f2/rj4RvYLCobY.jpg',
                name: 'Tatyana Plutalova',
                name_gen: 'Tatyana'
            },
            {
                id: 232745053,
                owner_id: 34,
                artist: 'Ambassadeurs',
                title: 'Sparks',
                duration: 274,
                url: 'http://cs6164.vk....M_lGEJhqRK8d5OQZngI',
                lyrics_id: 120266970,
                genre_id: 18
            },
            {
                id: 232733966,
                owner_id: 34,
                artist: 'Aloe Blacc',
                title: 'Can You Do This ',
                duration: 176,
                url: 'http://cs6157.vk....ZaerOa0DvsyOCYTPO1w',
                genre_id: 2
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: без примера json никто вам не подскажет. И неважно откуда он.

Comment: зачем же сюда кидать.  отредактируйте вопрос, где положите читабельный json

Comment: у вас какой-то не правильный JSON - почему после `url` или `photo` идет `;`? да и массив не закрыт

Comment: На самом деле , там двоеточие , это я копипастнул с вк дэв , там где разбор методов , там есть масив , что выдает метод audio.get

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @ДимаПотапов отредактировал ваш вопрос. В будущем любой код и структуры данных добавляйте в сам вопрос, но не публикуйте в комментариях.

Comment: Спасибо , понял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если предположить, что полученный json верен, то причина в неверной его обработке.

1. `JToken` и другие классы из этой библиотеки уже реализуют `IEnumerable` поэтому методы расширения можно вызывать сразу, а не через статический класс.
2. Чтобы получить массив `items` нужно просто его взять

   ```
   var items = token["response"]["items"];
   ```
3. Далее уже к нему применить метод `Select`

---

@ДимаПотапов, вы пробовали неверно. В вашем случае в селекте вы бежите по последовательности с одним элементом, который является массивом - и этот массив вы хотели десериализовать в объект класса Audio, и, закономерно, получили ошибку

Comment: JToken token = JToken.Parse(responseFromServer);
            audioList = token["response"].Children().Skip(1).Select(c => c.ToObject<Audio>()).ToList();

Comment: вот так я пробовал , но всеравно этовызывает у меня ошибку

Comment: An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unexpected token while deserializing object: PropertyName. Path '', line 1, position 33.

Comment: @ДимаПотапов, дополнил ответ